# How to specify response type in useFetch hook

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I have a `useFetch` custom hook implemented as follows:

```
function useFetchDemo<ResponseType>(url: string): {
  data: ResponseType;
} {
  const [data, setData] = useState<ResponseType | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((res) => setData(res["data"]));
  }, []);

  return { data };
}
```

I intend to use it like
`useFetch<UserInterface>("/users/123")` or `useFetch<PostInterface>("/posts/123")`, which allows me to specify the response data type based on which endpoint I am querying.

However, I am getting the error:

```
Type 'ResponseType | null' is not assignable to type 'ResponseType'.
  'ResponseType' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'ResponseType | null'.ts(2322)
```

Seems like I should be passing a different initial value to `useState` but I don't know what value I should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function useFetchDemo<ResponseType>(url: string): {
  data: ResponseType | null;
} {
  const [data, setData] = useState<ResponseType | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get<ResponseType>(url).then((res) => setData(res["data"]));
  }, []);

  return { data };
}
```

pass your response type to the axios get request. There is generic get method defined in axios/index.d.ts

```js
get<T = never, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig<T>): Promise<R>;
```

this way data will be the type you passed.

Next to that also add the null option to data

Comment: Thanks. Adding null option to data did the trick. Any extra benefit of passing response type to axios get request?

Comment: yes always prefer typed responses over non typed responses. say you wan't to use the response before setting it to data you'll have some nice autocomplete and also you will catch errors quicker